# Batch Print - Batch Script - findstr condition in for loop

Tags: ftp, batch-file

My problem at hand is to download pdf files and send all of them to the printer.

I download via ftp correctly and all the files go into my local directory:

File Name = FtpScript.ftp

```
open ftp.domain.com
username
password
!:--- FTP commands below here ---
lcd local/Directory
cd  /remote/Directory
binary
mget "*.pdf"
prompt
disconnect
quit
```

This batch file then calls the ftp script.

File Name = retrieve_print.bat

```
@ftp -i -s:"C:\Scripts\FtpScript.ftp"

set mm=%date:~4,2%
set dd=%date:~7,2%
set yy=%date:~-4%

IF NOT EXIST {C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%}( mkdir C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy% )

IF NOT EXIST C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\uploaded_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt ( 
    @echo Uploaded Text -- Date: %date% Time : %time%  >>     C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\uploaded_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt   
) 
IF NOT EXIST     C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\printed_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt ( 
    @echo Printed Text -- Date: %date% Time : %time% >>     C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\printed_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt 
)

REM LOOP THROUGH PDFs THAT WERE UPLOADED AND INSERT THE NAMES INTO THE UPLOADED_*_*.txt TEXT     FILE 
FOR %%x in (  C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\*.pdf )  DO     (
    findstr "%%~nxx"     C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\uploaded_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt
    @ECHO Error level = %errorlevel%
    @ECHO %%~nxx 
    @pause
    IF NOT %errorlevel% == 0 (
        @echo %%~nxx >>     C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\uploaded_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt
    )
)

REM LOOP THROUGH PDFs THAT WERE UPLOADED AND PRINT THEM, THEN INSERT THEM INTO THE PRINTED_*_*.txt TEXT FILE TO SUPPRESS DUPLICATE PRINTS 
FOR %%x in (  C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\*.pdf )  DO     (
    findstr "%%~nxx"     C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\printed_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt
    @ECHO Error level = %errorlevel%
    @ECHO %%~nxx 
    IF NOT %errorlevel% == 0 (
        rem PRINT FUNCTION
        @echo %%~nxx >>     C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\printed_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt
    )
)
```

The text files generate incorrectly. My thought is that I could loop through the files available in the print_test2/print_%mm%_%yy% directory for all the files that I received via ftp and log it into a text file.

The problem becomes apparent when I try to run the script a second time when the text files have file names in them. I expect the findstr function to give back an %errorlevel% of 0 , but it does not detect the string that is in the text file and appends all the file names again in both my uploaded and printed text files.

Is there a better way of logging the files received and printing the pdfs only once?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the `%errorlevel%` value is taken inside a for, so it is replaced by the value errorlevel had *before* enter the for loop. To take the *current* value that errorlevel have *in each for iteration* you must use Delayed Variable Expansion, that is, enclose the value in exclamation points instead percents: `!errorlevel!` AND insert this line at begining of your program:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

To make this problem clearer, try this:

```
set name=Value before FOR
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
   set name=%%f
   echo %name%
)
```

and then try again changing `echo %name%` by `echo !name!`.

Comment: Spent some time with this for loop and didn't know what was going on. This fixed my error exactly. Thanks for your help Aacini.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas to consider:

1. I'm not sure that the errorlevel after your FINDSTR command is going to be non-zero just because the string wasn't found.
2. Even if errorlevel is non-zero, I think that the moment you execute the next command, the new errorlevel from that command gets set.
3. In your IF statement, you might need to wrap the two sides of your equality check in delimiters, e.g. `IF NOT "%errorlevel%" == "0"`
4. You might consider just making your list distinct after you echo all file names into it.  It'll save you some logic on the way in.  Some code for making a list distinct in DOS is described here: http://www.dullsharpness.com/2010/10/01/create-a-distinct-ordered-list-from-an-unordered-duplicate-list-using-ms-dos/
5. If you use techniques from #4, you can then just do a directory listing into your file (as follows) and then make unique using techniques in #4.

`dir/b C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\*.pdf >> C:\Users\print_test2\print_%mm%_%yy%\printed_%mm%_%dd%_%yy%.txt`

Comment: 1. Yes, FINDSTR return a non-zero errorlevel value if the string wasn't found. 2. In .BAT files, ECHO and PAUSE commands does not modify the errorlevel. 3. When comparing errorlevel values the delimiters are not needed, only when the values may contain spaces or other special characters.

Comment: Hey Marc, the technique in 4 explains setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion very well. Especially with http://www.robvanderwoude.com/variableexpansion.php . Thanks!